# Unable to run the copy code in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am not able to run the below copy code, getting error `Application -defined or Object-Defined error`. This code was running earlier but is now giving the error. Please help me as I am not able to understand what went wrong.

```
For i = Start To last
'MsgBox ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 17).Value, vbInformation

If (ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 17).Value >= ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 34).Value) Then
    'MsgBox ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 17).Value, vbInformation
    Worksheets("Sample Data").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 2)).Copy
    Worksheets("Output").Cells(j, 2).PasteSpecial xlValues
    j = j + 1
End If

Next i
```

I am able to run it line by line but getting the error when pressing`f5`.

Comment: Have the worksheet names changed? Which line provides the error using F8?

Comment: @MiguelH No sheet names have been changed

Comment: You should *Qualify* the `Cells` to the worksheet. Easier yet, use this: `Worksheets("Sample Data").Cells(i, 1).Resize(,2).Copy`

Comment: @MiguelH `Worksheets("Sample Data").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 2)).Copy` is the line at error

Comment: @A.S.H this is not working , as its copying all the data which is not even satisfying the `IF` condition

Comment: @MiguelH, @A.S.H the lines are working on `f8` but not on `f5`.

Comment: Nikita, your use of `ActiveSheet` doesn't make sense to me. You probably want to replace it with `Worksheets("Sample Data")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code runs fine now on restart. This can be ignored as the code is correct.